# Node.js delegating functions to an imported module

Tags: node.js, events, eventemitter

Currently I have a Node.js module with the following form :

```
var events = require('events');
var emitter = new events.EventEmitter();

function emitSomething() {
    emitter.emit("event");
}
exports.emitSomething = emitSomething;
exports.on = emitter.on;
```

However any callback registered through `on` do not get called when I call `emitSomething`.

I can get around this by changing the last line to

```
exports.on = function(event, callback) { emitter.on(event, callback); };
```

Is there a reason I can't delegate the on function to a function defined in another module?

Comment: how do you "register" your callback with "on"?

Comment: @robkuz The same way I would register a callback with any EventEmitter so if my module was called "myModule" I would register it with myModule.on("event", function() { console.log("called");});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common JS mistake. Note that the `on` method depends on `this` (which is `emitter` in your example). However, all you export is the function itself, so it's  context (`emitter`) is lost when you call it later.

Here is a small example for this issue:

```
var someObj = { 
    doSth: function() { console.log(this) } 
};
someObj.doSth(); // "Object { ..."

var doSth = someObj.doSth;
doSth(); // "Window { ..."
```

When I call `doSth` as method of `someObj`, `this` references `someObj` as expected. After I copied the function to `doSth`, `this` references it's new context, in the browser the global context `Window`. This is what happens in your case.

As you already mentioned, you have to bind the `emitter` context to the function. This can also be done like this:

```
exports.on = emitter.on.bind(emitter);
```

Comment: Ahhh I didn't realise that using exports causing a binding to the "this" parameter. That is where I was getting stuck. Marking as answered.